# ORACLE SQL ignore to_date comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime-format

I'm stuck with a trivial date comparison:

my query return a set of 3 record, posted below

[image]

adding to the where clause the condition:

```
halaffecteddate <= to_date('20-03-20 23:43:00','dd-mm-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

it returns only one record (line 4)

Can someone could explain why?

Does it depend on the client's date format?

I'm using oracle sql developer

Comment: What is `halaffecteddate` column's datatype? By the way, if you pass '20-03-20', then use appropriate format mask; there are only 2 digits for year, don't use YYYY but YY (or RR?) or - even better - provide 4 digits for year.

Comment: "My query return set of 3 record" - image shows 4 records

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
to_date('20-03-20 23:43:00','dd-mm-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Will become a date of 20-MAR-**0020** 23:43:00 because specifying YYYY causes oracle to parse `20` as `0020` rather than `2020`

We can't really see what dates you truly have in your table, because they're two digits, but the only way that "just row 4" will be returned from this clause is if the date in the `halaffecteddate` of row 4 is also year `0020`. Perhaps add another column to your query: `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM haleffectivedate)` and see if it returns `20` or `2020` for row 4 - my guess is that it will return `20`

Comment: I do not agree -- `to_date('20-03-20 23:43:00','dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')` will become `20-03-0020 11:43:00`. see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65826b09b4a5a056fe0d487841f593c2)